# Insert items into an SQL table using a loop in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, loops

```
$loopCounter = 0;
            while ( $loopCounter < $amount ) {
                $sql = "INSERT INTO bookings VALUES (NULL, '$firstname', '$lastname', '$email', $enrolAmount, '$location', $price)";
                $loopCounter += 1;
                mysqli_query( $dbc, $sql );
            }
```

So I have a loop to try to insert items into an SQL table, but when ever I try this it only inserts one item into the table. Please help!

Comment: Where is $amount set?

Comment: Can u show us the declaration of $amount plz.

Comment: $amount = mysqli_real_escape_string( $dbc, $_POST['amount']); Its from a form

Comment: Well then clearly $amount is being set to 1. But why are you escaping it if you aren't using it in your query?

Comment: If I put echo "one"; just before the $sql and it comes up with "oneoneone"

Comment: Wait. What is the structure of your bookings table ? Please paste the output of `show create table bookings` sql command here. I think you got a primary / unique key somewhere and you simply get the next two inserts to fail ...

Comment: Table
Create Table
bookings
CREATE TABLE `bookings` (
 `bookings_id` tinyint(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `bookings_firstname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `bookings_lastname` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `bookings_email` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `bookings_people` int(2) NOT NULL,
 `trip_name` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
 `trip_price` decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`bookings_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=127 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8

Comment: check my answer, i think it is the fact that you are using tinyint for primary key and you have filled its range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a tinyint primary key which has reached its limit as denoted by

`AUTO_INCREMENT=127` in your comment. As per docs [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) maximum value for tinyint is 127.

You should run

`alter table bookings change column bookings_id bookings_id unsigned int(10) not null auto_increment primary key;`

and then you will most probably be ok.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Great example I found. 
Link [here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Insert-Multiple-Rows-Into-MySQL-The-Right-Way-With-PHP.html)

```
 <?php

// an array items to insert
$array = array( 'dingo'       => 'A native dog',
        'wombat'      => 'A native marsupial',
        'platypus'    => 'A native monotreme',
        'koala'       => 'A native Phascolarctidae'
        );

// begin the sql statement
$sql = "INSERT INTO test_table (name, description ) VALUES ";

// this is where the magic happens
$it = new ArrayIterator( $array );

// a new caching iterator gives us access to hasNext()
$cit = new CachingIterator( $it );

// loop over the array
foreach ( $cit as $value )
{
    // add to the query
    $sql .= "('".$cit->key()."','" .$cit->current()."')";
    // if there is another array member, add a comma
    if( $cit->hasNext() )
    {
        $sql .= ",";
    }
}


// now we can use a single database connection and query
$conn = mysql_connect('db_user', 'db_password' );
mysql_select_db( 'test_db', $conn );
mysql_query( $sql, $conn );

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use for instead of while

```
for($loopCounter = 0; $loopCounter < $amount; $loopCounter++)
```

Then, I think the reason why you insert only one item is because your $amout variable is probably set to 1. You should try to write

```
$amout = 2;
```

just before the loop to see if it is the problem.

Comment: If I put echo "one"; just before the $sql and it comes up with "oneoneone"